# Android 4.0 emulator won't start

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When trying to create and start an Android 4.0 emulator I get the Android emulator skin but the OS doesn't seem to start.

I've installed the ARM EABI v7 package from Android SDK manager at tried to create an emulator, but got an error message about a missing userdata.img file.

I then found that the system $ANDROD_LIB$/system-images/android-14/armeabi-v7a/ library was created and copied these files into $ANDRROID_LIB$/platforms/android-14/images/ after which I could create a the emulator image.

When starting this new emulator this as stated above only shows the Skin (window) but don't start the OS. Im on a Mac, and all previously created emulators still work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed rev 15 tools and with idea 110.291 I could choose armeabi-v76 start the emulator and restart it after 30 minutes and now it started.

Comment: What is `idea 110.291`? What is `armeabi-v76`? It only goes up to 7: `armeabi-v7a`. Why would the build tools matter when it's just the emulator running?

Answer (score 7):

A few tips: mine was also taking ages to start up (gave up after about 30mins). Then I compared the settings of my 3.1 AVD and my new 4.0 AVD. Turns out that the hardware property **Abstract LCD density** setting of the 4.0 AVD is set by default to 240, which means high density. That means a lot of pixels to draw. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284157/avd-very-slow-on-android-4-0) that that's one of the issues of a slow starting AVD. So I changed that property to be the same as for the 3.1, so it 160. After that, the AVD started about as fast as the 3.1 (several minutes)!

(Also reduced the Device ram size from 512 to 256, but don't think that was the one who fixed it)

Comment: This worked for me.  There's no way to do this through the AVD GUI (with the 22.0.1 sdk).  I had to edit config.ini under ~/.android/xxx.avd and modify hw.lcd.density.

Comment: Worked for me too. Also had to apply mooreds tip. Btw: using the intel atom image. Startup time is now by 20 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, have you set the GPU acceleration in the emulator option? I have set that in my emulator and the emulator wouldn't start... I was just seeing the frame like you said. Didn't really find a solution to this, except turning off GPU acceleration.

Answer (score 5):

My emulator was stuck on, "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...". This is how I solved it. In your ADT select Run Configurations and edit your virtual device to use host gpu by selecting the, "Use Host GPU" checkbox option in your edit device configuration window.

Answer (score 3):

I thought my Android 4.0 emulator was frozen too, but it turned out I just had to wait about 5 minutes for it to start up.

Comment: Sorry, don't seem to be my lack of patience. The emulator has now been running for 30 minutes on 100% CPU without showing anything in the 'screen'

Answer (score 2):

Once Check the TaskManager to check any adb/emulator is running.

If you find stop the services and restart the eclipse and create Emulator.

Answer (score -1):

To fix mine, I had to:

- open up the SDK manager,
- check the box next to "Android 4.0 (API 14) >> ARM EABI v7a System Image",
- then click the "Delete" button at the bottom.
- After it deleted, I restarted Eclipse.
- Then I went back in, checked the same box on the SDK manager again,
- and reinstalled it.
- Then restarted Eclipse again.

Now it is working.

Comment: When I did this, the AVD wouldn't start because it was missing the required kernel.